# Excel: Interpreting cell value as a table name

Tags: excel, reference, excel-2016, excel-indirect, excel-tables

I have a couple of different tables defined in Excel 2016 with identical layout, based on `Name` as the left-most key field. I am doing `VLOOKUP` against those tables based on the `Name` in a different table, which has `FieldName` and `TableName` columns, which I am supposed to use to search in the right place. So currently, I have code which looks like this:

```
VLOOKUP([@FieldName], IF([@TableName]="Static", Static, Dynamic), 2, FALSE)
```

And this works great when you only have 2 tables to search in, `Static` and `Dynamic`. However, when you have 5 or 6 of them, writing a string of nested `IF` does not result in a readable solution.

Is there a function I can call to transform the string value in `TableName` into an actual table reference? If not, is there any other way to do the same thing if I would like to stay out of VBA if at all possible.

Thank you very much

Comment: use INDIRECT().

Comment: @ScottCraner if you write it up, I will accept it as an answer. Thank you very much